# Getting a 403 from All Google Endpoints

Tags: http-status-code-403

I run a website that lets users login to their account via Google. For over a year, everything worked great - until a few days ago, when Google started throwing 403 errors when the server tries to access any of their OAuth certificate listing API endpoints.

For example:

```bash
$ curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs'
...
<p><b>403.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/oauth2/v3/certs</code> from this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
...
```

This request works fine on every other server that I've tried it on, and it worked for years. I'm not sure why this so suddenly started happening.

The server has its own IP, though it is hosted on a small, no-name VPS provider. My initial thought was rate limiting, but I've added logs and don't see many requests being made. The only other thing I can think of is IP address reputation problems, by being close in address to an abuser? Not sure how/if that is solvable.

Any ideas on how to fix/debug this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No logging, and shut off? Probably a defect that caused excessive requests. Or abuse originating from your IP address. If it works everywhere but that IP it got on a list. It could be an unrelated list, for example VirusTotal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Google was blocking all requests from my server's IPv**6** address. The solution is to switch the server to IPv**4** by default - this fixed everything!

On Ubuntu:

1. Edit `vim /etc/gai.conf` and uncomment the line after "For sites which prefer IPv4 connections"
2. Run `systemctl restart systemd-resolved`
3. Restart your backend server processes